# Setting up a database in glassfish server 4.1

Tags: java-8, oracle12c, glassfish-4.1

As specified in oracle [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/ggkon.html#gharl) I'm trying to setup a database in glassfish server. my JDK version is 1.8 and the glassfish is 4.1. I'm using the ojdbc7.jar.

I've put the ojdbc into \glassfish\domains\domain1\lib\ext folder and re-started both server and the database. But when I try to ping, an error comes as:

```
Ping Connection Pool failed for TestPool. Connection could not be allocated because: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

in server.log I found:

```
2015-04-13T18:35:25.413+0530] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [test.connection.pool.failed] [javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1428930325413] [levelValue: 900] [[
  RAR8054: Exception while creating an unpooled [test] connection for pool [ TestPool ], Connection could not be allocated because: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection]]
```

But I can ping "Derby Pool" which is in glassfish by default successfully. I've setup all the Connection pool properties and JVM options as mentioned in the documents.

Can someone please help to setup this correctly?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The driver seems to have problems connecting to the oracle instance.

Make sure you can make the connection from the glassfish to the oracle server.  Especially check the hostname / port (the default oracle portnumber is 1521).

Comment: I used ojdbc6.jar too. But same results.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snapshot of my setup:
[image]

[image]

But while trying to ping, I found these on server log:

```
RAR8054: Exception while creating an unpooled [test] connection for pool [ TEST ], Connection could not be allocated because: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection]]
```

Is this due to a server error, because I'm using glassfish 4.1.

Comment: Is the oracle database installed on the same host? Is the service running?

Comment: First, those properties aren't required. With three of them you do the job (User, Password, URL). Also before connect with glassfish, test your connection with sqlplus or sqldeveloper, for example; if you can connect with any of those tools, then you shouldn't have problems.

Hope this help